# Opening for Anonymous Pipes Perl Programming

Tags: perl

How to test whether any of the files listed have been modified in the last 12 hours in perl programming. Print the names of those files.

Here is my code, but it does not work. Could anyone teach me how to fix it?

```
use warnings;
  open(LISTDIR, "find ~ -type f -mtime 0 -ls /Users/Perl/ |  ") or die "PIPE failed $!\n";
  while( $filename = <LISTDIR> ){
     print $filename;
   }
```

Comment: The -ls doesn't take an argument.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I hope ls those files in the last 12 hours, but it ls all of them.

Comment: @Johnny `-mtime 0` will return everything modified in the last 24 hours, not 12 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use warnings;
open(LISTDIR, "find ~ -type f -mtime 0 -ls |  ") or die "PIPE failed $!\n";
while( $filename = <LISTDIR> ){
    print $filename;
}
```

You should have seen an error message:

```
find: paths must precede expression: /Users/Perl
```

which explains everything.

Comment: Don't forget to close the filehandle and check the success of `close`; with piped opens, `open` only returns whether `fork` was successful, not whether the invoked program was.

Comment: I hope ls those files in the last 12 hours, but it ls all of them.